# HandlerSSHTunnelForwarderError with SSHTunnelForwarder

Tags: postgresql, ssh, sqlalchemy, paramiko, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to connect to my remote postgres db as follows:

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder #Run pip install sshtunnel
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker #Run pip install sqlalchemy

with SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('10.160.1.24', 22), #Remote server IP and SSH port
    ssh_username = "<usr>",
    ssh_password = "<pwd>",
    remote_bind_address=('10.160.1.24', 5432),
    local_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3334)
    ) as server:

    server.start() #start ssh sever
    print 'Server connected via SSH'

    #connect to PostgreSQL
    local_port = str(server.local_bind_port)
    engine = create_engine('postgresql://<db_user>:<db_pwd>@127.0.0.1:' + local_port +'/<db_name>')

    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

    print 'Database session created'

    #test data retrieval
    test = session.execute("SELECT * FROM <table_name>")
```

This is the output that I see:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sshtunnel.py", line 299, in handle
raise HandlerSSHTunnelForwarderError(msg)
HandlerSSHTunnelForwarderError: In #1 <-- ('127.0.0.1', 54265) to ('10.160.1.24', 5432) failed: ChannelException(2, 'Connect failed')
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I am able to connect to the postgresdb by running the command `ssh -L 3334:localhost:5432 Administrator@10.160.1.24` in a seperate terminal and then connecting to the db at localhost:3334.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my mistake!

`remote_bind_address=('10.160.1.24', 5432)` should be `remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 5432),`